# How to log uWSGI vassal metrics in emperor mode?

Tags: uwsgi, metrics

We're using uWSGI in Emperor mode.  We want to be able to track the default (non-custom) metrics like `worker.0.requests`, and we're trying to use the `metrics-dir` configuration parameter in the vassals' ini files.  For example:

```
enable-metrics = true
metrics-dir = /tmp/pametrics
```

Files *are* being written to the directory we specify, and their timestamps are being updated each time we hit the app being served by the vassal, but they are all 4096 bytes long and full of zero bytes; they are not text files as [the documentation says](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Metrics.html#the-metrics-directory).

What are we missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are memory mapped files so their size is the same of a memory page.

Being 0 terminated, you can use the classic unix utilities to manage them

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  It's very odd; when we looked at the files yesterday, it looked like they were full of zero bytes -- no text values at the start.  But looking at them now, I can see numbers at the start.  I guess we must have missed them before somehow.